# Compile Error: Argument Not Optional when Argument is supplied

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

Hi I keep getting a Compile error: Argument not optional in my VBA excel code when I have supplied arguments function used. The Main purpose of the function is to record values from one workbook and save into another as an audit log.  However I get the error above and can't find a solution because it looks like I have supplied arguments to every function component that requires it.

```
Public Sub LogResults ()
  Call RecordAudit(CreateCollection)
End Sub

Public Function CreateCollection() As Collection
       Dim colProspectValues As New Collection
       Dim ManRateCredibility As Double
       ManRateCredibility = 0
       ManRateCredibility = CDbl(1 - worksheets("whorksheetname").Range("A1").Value)

       colProspectValues.Add Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("A2").Value
       colProspectValues.Add Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("A3").Value
       colProspectValues.Add Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("A4").Value
       colProspectValues.Add Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("A5").Value
       colProspectValues.Add Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("A6").Value
       colProspectValues.Add ManRateCredibility 
      
       Set CreateCollection = colProspectValues

End Function

  Public Sub RecordAudit(ByRef aCollection As Collection)
       Dim tempCollection as Collection
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim wbMaster As Workbook
       Dim wbLocal As Workbook
       Dim MasterNextRow As Long
       Dim AuditLogPath As String
       
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Set tempCollection = aCollection
     AuditLogPath = "H:\FolderB\Model\ProspectAudit.xlsx"
     Set wbMaster = Workbooks(AuditLogPath)
     MasterNextRow = wbMaster.Worksheets("AuditLog").Range("B" & wbMaster.Worksheets("AuditLog").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

     For i = 1 to tempCollection.count
          wbMaster.Worksheets("AuditLog").Cells(MasterNextRow, i).Value = 
          tempCollection.Item(i)
     Next i

  End Sub
```

Comment: you have End Collection at end. Not End Sub.

Comment: Thanks that was typo when entering the code here.  The prod environment does have end Sub in it not end collection

Comment: Exactly where is the error?   Your last Sub has no name ...?

Comment: The lastSub is named Public Sub RecordAudit(Byref aCollection As Collection)  when entering debug it highlight the CreateCollection function

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Please state which line throws the error.

Comment: RecordAudit is a sub not a function therefore the correct call is `RecordAudit CreateCollection` not `Call RecordAudit(CreateCollection)` Not sure why you are passing ByRef however or why using an interim collection as you are only needing the values from the original collection passed in.

Comment: When you get a compiler error in VBA, it shows you **exactly** which line causes the issue. You should include information about which line it is, either by identifying it in your text or by adding a comment in the code. You're asking us for free help solving a problem that you're having, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the information you already have on the screen in front of you.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what it was.

I had not fully defined the function required when setting the workbook path using

```
Workbooks.Open(AuditLogPath)
```

instead of

```
Workbooks(AuditLogPath)
```